# mysql left join exists

Tags: mysql

Tables:

- users: id, name
- usersFacebookFriends: id, uid, friendUid, name

I need a query to search for friends (name), and check if they exists in the users table, so then they are also on the website registered.

Is this possible with a left join, and if so how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this should make a job. If facebook friend is not registered with your site corrsponding joined User table fields will be NULL.

```
SELECT f.name, u.* FROM usersFacebookFriends AS f
LEFT JOIN users AS u
ON f.friendUid = u.id
WHERE f.uid = 123
```

Change `LEFT JOIN` to `INNER JOIN` if you need to find only those who exist.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT ff.id, ff.uid, ff.friendUid, ff.name, u.id, u.name
    FROM usersFacebookFriends ff
        LEFT JOIN users u
            ON ff.name = u.name;
```

If you want only those that exist:

```
SELECT ff.id, ff.uid, ff.friendUid, ff.name, u.id, u.name
    FROM usersFacebookFriends ff
        INNER JOIN users u
            ON ff.name = u.name;
```

If you want only those that don't exist:

```
SELECT ff.id, ff.uid, ff.friendUid, ff.name, u.id, u.name
    FROM usersFacebookFriends ff
        LEFT JOIN users u
            ON ff.name = u.name
    WHERE u.id IS NULL;
```